Common terminology for the set $\{\varphi(x) : \varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)\}$ for an element $x$ of a group $G$
If $G$ is a group and $x \in G$, is there terminology referring to the orbit of $x$ under the action of the automorphism group? That is, the set $\{\varphi(x) : \varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)\}$?
The L-functions and modular forms database (LMFDB) gives this object the name autjugacy class, see here. But, a Google search for this term gives only three relevant results.
Is there a more commonly used name given to this object?

Autjugacy is a gross word, but is a generalization of conjugacy class, which is the orbits of the elements under the inner automorphisms I suppose

"automorphism orbits"?

« Aut$(G)$-orbit », and « Aut$(G)x$ », « Aut$(G)(x)$ », « $x^{\text{Aut}(G)}$ », or « $^{\text{Aut}(G)}x$ » : These are the shortest terms containing all the information you require wrt a common mathematically educated reader - that is, those terms follow common mathematics namemaking rules and are the 1+4 shortest such terms. Why look for a less efficient name ?

@plm: Besides notation one often wants words, i.e. vocal terminology, even at the expense of more keystrokes.

@LeeMosher, Thanks, of course, and i feel the terms above are also practical to pronounce and intuitive. I would argue they are even easier to understand than "autjugacy class".

I'm with you on autjugacy, which is why I wrote my answer.

It's difficult to give any kind of authoritative negative answer to this question, but as far as I know, no, there isn't a more commonly used name given to this object, I've never seen anyone give it a name at all (in the category of groups or any other category). "Autjugacy" is quite awkward but at least it's basically clear what it means. You could call it the $\text{Aut}$-orbit or the $\text{Aut}$-class, or maybe use a term like "associates," although that's significantly more ambiguous.

The term automorphic orbit is somewhat common, at least in the context where $G$ is a finite rank free group. Doing a title search of the phrase "automorphic orbit" on MathSciNet gets you 10 or so hits over the years 1998-2014, mostly regarding free groups (but some in broader settings of algebra). Including a search of reviews in addition gives maybe double that number of hits.
This goes back to a problem of Whitehead, who found an algorithm to determine (in this language) whether two elements of a finite rank free group are in the same automorphic orbit.
